# What's the most popular method for Cordova/Ionic push notification?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm new guy in hybrid mobile development and what I want to know is what are most popular methods for Cordova/Ionic push notification(not local notification)?

Does anyone know has some guidelines or Tutorial for this field?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Tutorial still works fine: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Here you have a german one: http://www.cordova-forum.de/index.php/Thread/99-Cordova-Push-Notification-Tutorial-iOS-Phonegap/

You will need this Plugin for that: [Cordova PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin)

And here finaly a tutorial for android: http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/tutorial-push-notifications-sample-app

Comment: Is this method just for IOS? Actually I need a solution can apply to two platforms(android,IOS) at least.

Comment: I added a link for android, sorry - i forgot that.